# Errors messages re: Flags and Genesis file when initialising a private blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, genesis

I used to initialise a private blockchain in this way:

```
geth --identity "Prashant" --fast --cache=1024 --jitvm --rpc  --rpcport "8013" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "myPrivateNetwork2" --port "30312"  --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,admin,debug,miner,personal,web3" --autodag --networkid 1902 --nat "any" init customGenesis.json console
```

I tried that again after a long time and I am getting an error message stating that `--jitvm, --ipcapi, --autodag` flags are provided but no defined.

Are these flags completely deprecated, or are there alternatives?  How can I specify what`ipc apis` I need to expose?

**I am also getting this issue**:

> Fatal: invalid genesis file: hex string has odd length

My `genesis.json` is this:

```
{
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
    "timestamp": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x0",
    "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
    "difficulty": "0x400",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
    "alloc":{}
}
```

I have read other threads on the Genesis issue, all suggesting to use the latest version of geth, but I am already using it.

**Edit**:
The genesis issue was **resolved** by making `extraData` value an even length (0x00), as well as I needed to add a config to the `customGenesiss.json`,

```
    "extraData": "0x00",
    "config": {
            "chainId": 15,
            "homesteadBlock": 0,
            "eip155Block": 0,
            "eip158Block": 0
        }
```

Comment: Can you try making the `extraData` value an even length? (e.g. `0x00`.)

Comment: Making it even worked. But now it's : `failed to write genesis block: genesis has no chain configuration`. And if you could explain why I need to make it even.

Comment: which version do you have? because i've tried same options with geth 1.5.9-stable and it didn't raise any error

Comment: I have  geth 1.6.0-stable-facc47cb. A lot of things changes when you come back to ethereum after some time :p

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer...

The `jitvm` flag is deprecated. See [#2365](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2365), though it was actually removed as part of [#13875](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/13875/commits/766ce7abca39c750a2e1b635139b3a535b8d5359).

The `autodag` flag is also deprecated, and is now the default behaviour. See the thread for [#3768](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3768). (I can't immeidately find when it was removed, though.)

Comment: strange but they are still listed in geth help!!